Could there be only one layer of dense clouds in the atmosphere?
Several times when I flew in a passenger plane in daylight, I saw a dense layer of clouds under the plane or above the plane.
This dense layer of clouds totally "hid" what's beyond it, so that either I couldn't see the land below it or I couldn't see the atmosphere above it.
Could there be only one (such) layer of dense clouds in the atmosphere?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud

I think it's a bit unclear what you're asking - that's why the downvotes might come in - as you clearly state you've seen multiple layers of clouds yourself when flying - so there is your answer? Also what are "sky clouds" as opposed to "clouds"? Note also that cirrus clouds exist, and high-altitude noctilucent clouds, which I am sure are basic weather education for any pilot.

Thanks @AtmosphericPrisonEscape. I have changed the question to a more well-defined one.

It's still a bit unclear to me what the question is. The part " (or in some days there could be two or more such layers)" is again answered in your question.
Are you asking about a globally covering single layer of clouds? Notice also that clouds are formed depending on how how the initial gas parcel on the ground was that they're stemming from. So topography alone will introduce different vertical layers.

@AtmosphericPrisonEscape thanks again; I have further shortened and sharped the question so it is even more clear and well defined now in my humble opinion; other than that, I can't see how to further improve the question. Please take a last look and if you can, share with us an answer. Thank you !!!

Are you asking: 1 - can there be two such layers?  2 - Is it possible to have a planet with such a layer all the way around it?  or something else?

There can be more than one level of clouds. See the below image as an example.  Sourced from University of Hawaii here.

A cumulonimbus cloud rises and expands as a product of instability within the atmosphere
